# How to connect Access to SQL database using SQL Sever 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an application on Access that stores data from the form into a database. I've tried connecting to the SQL Database instead but I can't seem to see any records I've input during testing.

The steps I've performed to go about this are as follows:

> 1) I got Write permissions on the SQL database. Created a new test
>   table successfully to make sure of permissions.
>   2) Start / Run "ODBCAD32.exe" - Created a DSN for that SQL Server using SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
>       3) We use Windows Authentication, so made sure that was selected.
>       4) Entered the correct details for the Server and the database in question.
>       5) Tested Data Source which completed successfully.
>       6) On Access, clicked on ODBC Database in External Data tab.
>       7) Selected Link to the datasource by creating a linked table.
>       8) Machine Data Source tab - selected my datasource and clicked on OK.
>       9) I now get a list of tables - dbo.table1....dbo.table 99
>       10) Clicked on Select All and clicked on OK.
>       11) Now I keep getting a window for each linked table asking to Select Unique Record Identifier. I selected the unique keys for a few
>   but there are hundreds of tables.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I connect my Access application to the SQL database?

Comment: Do these tables have **Primary Keys** on SQL Server? If no, this behavior is normal. If yes, Access should detect it automatically and not ask for it.

Comment: As already stated, you really should assign primary keys in SQL Server. Should this not be possible for some reason, you could link the tables programmaticlly and assign primary keys on the Access side. Don't bother with an ADP as ADPs are no longer supported. You would be stuck using an older version of Access.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design and there is no good workaround for it. Your table in SQL lacks a primary key and so Access is asking you how to uniquely identify a record in the table so that it can perform CRUD operations against the table.

You can either:

1. Suffer through properly linking your tables by identifying the unique primary key for each table.
2. Enter through without picking any fields (you will essentially be in read-only mode for those tables then)
3. Put primary keys on your tables in SQL Server before linking them. <--this would be the best option and should have been done when the table was created.

Comment: Plus one for Option 3, assuming there actually are no PKs.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of MS Access projects:

MDB projects can contain tables, forms, reports, macros, and modules.  They can link to ODBC and text file database sources.  This is what you have now.

ADP projects can contain forms, reports, macros, modules, and can link ONLY to SQL Server.  You can link to ONE SQL Server and the project automatically sees everything available to your SQL Server database user.  You don't ever need to configure ODBC.

If your front end only needs to connect to SQL Server, try building with the ADP project type.  More [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Access-project-89c48da0-55a4-45d4-9ee5-95f67383d4cb) (search for "ADP").